# Set static variable in another class (Zend Framework)

Tags: php, zend-framework, static

I'm want to use a variable like $_SESSION in Zend Framework, I use one class with holds a static variable like here:

```
class Login {
    private static $login = "false";
    public static function changeStatus($status)
    {
        self::$login = $status;
        print_r(self::$login);
    }
    public static function returnStatus()
    {
        return self::$login;
    }
}
```

After that, when I logged in successful, I will call Login::changeStatus function and pass "true" to this function in AuthAction, something like this:

```
Login::changeStatus("true");
$this->_redirect('/user/list');
```

but in listAction, I tried to get value of Login::$login, it still remains "false".
So how can I change Login::$login to "true" and when I access it from listAction(), I will get "true"?

I tried to use Zend_Registry as doydoy44 said, but I got this message "No entry is registered for key 'login'" :(.

Answer (score 1):

your static variable is declared as private, so I don't think you can access this variable Login::$login from your controller.

The simplest way should be to declare this variable as public, and stop using any accessors if these are useless. (or use your Login::returnStatus() method in your controller)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Zend_Registry](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.registry.using.html) for that like this:

```
// In authAction instead of Login::changeStatus("true"); :
Zend_Registry::set('login', true);

// In listAction:
if (Zend_Registry::isRegistered('login'))
    $login = Zend_Registry::get('login');
else
    $login = false;
```

I hope it will help you. :)

Comment: Sorry but when I used this, I got No entry is registered for key 'login' :(.